# Getting Invalid Request Body and Failed to post error using NextJS + MongoDB + Prisma ORM

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to send POST request from the Posts file, and I'm getting this below error, I'm hitting to the wrong endpoint or what?

```bash
Error parsing request body: ReferenceError: title is not defined
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/posts/index.js:7:12)
    at M:\Projects\squeeze\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\pages-api.runtime.dev.js:21:3039
    at M:\Projects\squeeze\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\trace\tracer.js:133:36
    at NoopContextManager.with
```

I'm trying to push `post title` and a boolean `true/false` from the post form. But I'm getting a lot errors,

Below code is of Posts.tsx located ./components/Posts.tsx

```js
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  title: String;
  published: boolean;
};

const Posts = (props: Props) => {
  const [postTitle, setPostTitle] = React.useState<any>("");
  const [published, setPublished] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const createPosts = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!postTitle) {
      alert("Title is required");
      return;
    }
    try {
      const apiURL = "/api/posts";
      const requestedData = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: postTitle, published }),
      };
      const response = await fetch(apiURL, requestedData);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      if (!response.ok) {
        alert(`Failed to post : ${postTitle}`);
        return;
      }
      setPostTitle("");
      setPublished(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={postTitle}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPostTitle(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <input type="text" className="text-black" onChange={(e) => {}} />
      <button onClick={createPosts} className="text-white">
        Create Posts
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

API code

pages/api/posts/index.js

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    ({ title, published } = req.body);
    if (!title) {
      throw new Error("Title is missing in request body");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing request body:", error);
    res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid request body" });
    return;
  }
}
```

Prisma Schema

```js
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Post {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title     String
  published Boolean  @default(false)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}
```

Kindly help me, I'm new to API routing, and all. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is the way you are trying to destructure the `req.body` in you API route handler.

```
// This line is causing the error
    ({ title, published } = req.body); // Incorrect destructuring assignment
```

When you're destructuring objects in JavaScript, you should either do it within the context of a declaration (using `const`, `let`, or `var`), or if you're destructuring an already declared object, you should not use an assignment without a declaration.

To fix this issue, you should modify the line where you're trying to extract title and published from `req.body`. You should add `const` or `let` in front of the curly braces to properly declare these variables

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    // Correct the destructuring by adding 'const'
    const { title, published } = req.body; // Corrected destructuring assignment
    if (!title) {
      throw new Error("Title is missing in request body");
    }
    // Your logic here...
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing request body:", error);
    res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid request body" });
    return;
  }
}
```